# Segmentation fault in traversing a LinkedList

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm new to C++ and pointers in general, but I can't seem to explain as to why I get segmentation fault in one of my two nearly identical code. I am doing a trivial task of traversing a `LinkedList`, here is the first way I do it:

```
Node * curNode = head; //Head is the pointer to the head of the LinkedList
while(curNode) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

This produces the desired result and traverses the entire LinkedList successfully. However, this raises a `Segmentation fault` error:

```
Node * curNode = head;
while(curNode->next != NULL) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

Changing the conditional to a casted boolean value or `!= nullptr` does nothing, so it isn't the case that the conditional is raising `true` on null pointers. And yet, I can't seem to figure out why I get a `Segmentation fault`, it seems like the appropriate loop condition ensures I don't access any null pointers.

Comment: If `head` is a null pointer the second code snippet introduces undefined behavior.

Comment: can you post the whole code...as this seems fine to me

Comment: I ran this on a test case where head is not a `null` pointer

Comment: The second version will obviously fail if `head` is `NULL`.  In this case, the loop will cause a segmentation fault right at the top of the first iteration, since it will attempt to dereference `NULL` (with a small offset).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I realized what was wrong, the site was running three test cases in the background but ONLY showed the `std:input` of one of those three test cases. The segmentation fault did come from one hidden test case where the input was `NULL`..... sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite:

```
Node * curNode = head;

// presumably, head is initialized somehow in omitted code

while(curNode->next != NULL) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

has two serious things wrong with it. One is the comparatively trivial problem that it doesn't consider the case when `head` is null. This causes a crash.

The second problem is that it's still *algorithmically incorrect* even if the first problem is addressed. It neglects to traverse the last node of the list.

If `curNode` is a non-null pointer, but `curNode->next` is null, this means "we have a valid node, which has no successor: `curNode` is the last node".

Thus the loop guard condition `while (curNode->next != NULL)` means "while `curNode` is not the last node".  It is not equivalent to the first loop, which traverses the entire list, including the last node.

If traversing all but the last node is what you want, then it is correct, and we can understand why the `head` test is needed: if `head` is null, then the list is empty, and therefore **it has no last node**. Since it has no last node, an empty list cannot be partitioned into "last node" and "everything else". That is why it is a special case, and why the extra null check exists just for the sake of the special case. We can write it like this:

```
Node * curNode = head;

if (head) {  // list is not empty: visit all but the last node
    while (curNode->next != NULL) {
        curNode = curNode->next;
    }
} else { // special case: list has no last node
   // do nothing? Or maybe some special behavior.
}
```

If we don't need any special behavior for the special case (it is okay to do nothing), then we can write it like this:

```
while (head && curNode->next != NULL) { // fold the if test into the while
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

We are wastefully testing `head` on each iteration of the loop; however, the compiler can easily optimize that away since `head` isn't modified in the loop body. This is also possible:

```
while (curNode && curNode->next != NULL) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

However, it wastefully tests `curNode` on each iteration of the loop. We know `curNode` can never be null except just before the first iteration. On subsequent iterations, the value of `curNode` is obtained from `curNode->next`, and we know that `curNode->next` isn't null, because that was the condition on entry into the iteration.  Maybe your compiler can figure this out also, though it requires a deeper analysis than optimizing away the access to `head`. The compiler has to follow the same data flow reasoning, that `curNode` is obtained from `curNode->next`, which is not null, but that this is only true in the second and subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 5):

The only case where I can see this throwing a segfault is if the `head` pointer itself is `NULL`.

To ensure that `head` is not `NULL`, the following should work and prevent the segfault:

```
Node * curNode = head;
if (head) {
    while(curNode->next != NULL) {
        curNode = curNode->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are not identical:

```
while(curNode->next != NULL) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

There is no initial check on `curNode` in this second version.

So, you need to check for `curNode` too:

```
while(curNode && curNode->next) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

Or start with an exta check outside the loop:

```
if(curNode) // This will also check for the case where `head` would be `NULL`
    while(curNode->next) {
        curNode = curNode->next;
    }
}
```

But this would skip the last item in the list. So your first version is preferred:

```
while(curNode) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `curNode` is `NULL` too :

```
Node * curNode = head;
while(curNode && curNode->next != NULL) {
    curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet is fine, so `Segmentation fault` error may occur only if head is `NULL`.